# What set is the best value for what you pay (lowest average cost per brick)?

Tags: sets, value, bricks-and-pieces, mosaic

Which Lego set is the best value for its cost? What I mean, is if you were to find the average cost per brick, which set would be the lowest? I feel like it would be something with lots of tiny pieces, like a mosaic, but not sure what exactly it is.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "vaue", really. Number of parts? Rare minifigs? Play time?

Comment: @IvanSanchez : the op specifies "lowest average cost per brick" as their criterium for best value.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think this question is unfairly getting downvoted and close voted. I find the question to be clear and with a straightforward and useful answer. I suspect the title is part of the culprit, so I've augmented it with what was specified in the body of the question.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker In that case, this is a duplicate of https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/9545/what-sets-have-the-best-price-per-part-ratio/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What sets have the best price per part ratio?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/9545/what-sets-have-the-best-price-per-part-ratio)

Comment: @IvanSanchez : so it is. I missed it.

Comment: For miscellaneous building, I can get a 1300 piece parts box for $50 at Costco when they're on sale. For specific MOCs, since I don't build much, I've found ordering exactly the needed pieces the most cost effective.

Answer (score 3):

Brickset allows you to sort sets by "price per piece" if that's the metric you're interested in. Go to [the sets browser](https://brickset.com/sets/year-2023), select a year and/or theme, and choose to sort by "Price per piece".

For 2023 eg., that yields the limited availability set [66747 Animal Play Pack](https://brickset.com/sets/66747-1/Animal-Play-Pack) with 486 pieces at a recommended retail price of $14.97, coming to only 3.1c per piece.

As you suspected, sets with lots of small parts can have an even lower price per piece. For example, set [41935 Lots of DOTS](https://brickset.com/sets/41935-1/Lots-of-DOTS) contains 1040 pieces (all 1x1 tiles of different shapes and colors) at a recommended retail price of $19.99, coming to only 1.9c per piece.